# How can I get rid of a stuck folder in the Finder's toolbar?

Tags: finder

I was trying to reorganize my desktop and had a folder dragging into another folder.

When I did this, the folder just got stuck in the toolbar and didn't copy over to the new location...

It's not a clickable button as if it were a favorites in the toolbar itself.

When I try to drag and drop it away from the toolbar, it doesn't work.

I then right clicked and went into "Customize Toolbar" and it wasn't in any of the lists for me to take it off.

Obviously its a 'favorites' feature, but how do I get the thing to get off all my finder toolbars now?

Comment: You will probably need to delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebar.plist, log out ad back in.  I like to make sure reopen windows is unchecked when I log out for the reset.

Comment: @ephsmith Thats just for the sidebar, not the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dragging and dropping while holding down <kbd>Command</kbd> nor dragging the folder out after selecting *Configure Toolbar* works you can:

1. Open **~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist**
2. Go to **NSToolbar Configuration Browser / TB Item Identifiers**, identify the problematic folder. If it's the only folder in the toolbar, will be the only **com.apple.finder.loc** item. If not, identifying it is pretty straightforward.
3. Delete that item, log out and then log back in.

Comment: how does one "Open ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist" ?   also, what does it mean, "relog"  ?

Comment: @Cheeso In Lion: While in finder click on *Go* (on the menu bar) while holding down <kbd>Option</kbd> and select *Library*, look for the *Preferences* folder and then the *com.apple.finder.plist* file. For opening an editing a *.plist* file, the best option is using **Xcode**. And relog means *Loging Out* of the current user and *Log In* again. Just, on the Finder's Menu Bar, click * > Close Session [Your User Name]* and log int again.

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't know if this is what you mean, but I accidentally dragged a folder into the Finder, and when I removed it a question mark appeared.

How to delete an accidentally-dragged-in folder in the Finder toolbar:

Just hold <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> and drag the folder out of the Finder window and whoosh it's gone.

Comment: YES! This works and is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with a folder that got stuck in my sidebar, with no right-click option displaying. I tried removing preference files, etc.

Hold <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> and click and drag the icon away from the toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

right click on the item and remove from sidebar is there.

Comment: That's remove from sidebar not toolbar